# Will a TableLayout supply a vertical scrollbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, android-scrollview, android-tablelayout

Or will I have to incorporate a ScrollView into the TableLayout? Is this even possible? I want to dynamically create any number of rows for a screen, but need the rows to be scrollable.

I've been trying in vain to get this to work using LinearLayout for too long now, and think it's time to move either to TableLayout or RelativeLayout -- any comments on the preferability of one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the "list"-style views will automatically do scrolling.  LinearLayout, TableLayout, RelativeLayout, none of them do it because (like other people pointed out) it's so easy to wrap them in a ScrollView, it's just functionality that they don't need.

Comment: OK, thanks; I'm going to post my theoretical layout and see if anybody throws mud at it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use table layout within scroll layout then it is possible.
for example,

```
<ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

You can use table layout instead of Linear layout..

Comment: Yes, I know I can use TableLayout; my question is, will the TableLayout add a vertical scrollbar when there are too many rows to display on the screen?

Comment: @ Clay Shannon : Yes it will work...Just try it out..and if it doesn't then let me know...

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a `ScrollView` for your `TableLayout` just as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <TableLayout 
            android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:shrinkColumns="1"/>     

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```